# How do I insert a pandas DataFrame to an existing PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` and a PostgreSQL table `my_table`. I wish to truncate `my_table` and insert `df` (which has columns in the same order) into `my_table`, without affecting the schema of `my_table`. How do I do this?

In a rather naive attempt, I tried dropping `my_table` and then using `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`, but this creates a new table with a different schema.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would manually truncate the table and then simply let Pandas do its job:

```
con.execute('TRUNCATE my_table RESTART IDENTITY;')
df.to_sql('my_table', con, if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Could you tell me what the 'RESTART IDENTITY' bit does? I did refer the PostgreSQL docs just now, but couldn't understand what it means; "Automatically restart sequences owned by columns of the truncated table(s)".

Comment: @TrainHeartnet, you may want to read about [PostgreSQL sequnces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLyJC_rc7RAhVGhiwKHbUHDFYQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.neilconway.org%2Fdocs%2Fsequences%2F&usg=AFQjCNEcB_UHiN_9ojNJPKJiplHnEDKnhQ&sig2=ACv_GtfVhJmnHofkooljSw). You can omit `RESTART IDENTITY` if you don't have sequences in the `my_table` table

Comment: You could skip the manual truncation and do a single line: `df.to_sql('my_table', con, if_exists='replace')`

Comment: What if I need to execute an UPSERT statement?